# Trying to read password protected PDF using PyPDF2 raises struct.error

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am trying to read a password protected PDF, I have the password.

I tried the following:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

input_path = r'D:\report.pdf'
output_path = r'D:\report'
output_file = 'report_test.pdf'
password = 'REDACTED'

def decrypt_pdf(input_path, output_path, password):
    with open(input_path, 'rb') as input_file, \
            open(output_path, 'wb') as output_file:
        reader = PdfFileReader(input_file)
        reader.decrypt(password)

        writer = PdfFileWriter()

        for i in range(reader.getNumPages()):
          writer.addPage(reader.getPage(i))

        writer.write(output_file)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<input>", line 10, in decrypt_pdf
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1987, in decrypt
    return self._decrypt(password)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 1997, in _decrypt
    user_password, key = self._authenticateUserPassword(password)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2039, in >_authenticateUserPassword
    encrypt.get("/EncryptMetadata", BooleanObject(False)).getObject())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2973, in _alg35
    key = _alg32(password, rev, keylen, owner_entry, p_entry, id1_entry)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py", line 2876, in _alg32
    p_entry = struct.pack('<i', p_entry)
struct.error: argument out of range
```

Is there a different module I should be using? I looked up `qpdf` but `pip` won't install it.

Comment: what are the arguments you passed into the function?

Answer (score 0):

PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use `pypdf`. It received a lot of updates in 2022, see https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/encryption-decryption.html:

```
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("encrypted-pdf.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

if reader.is_encrypted:
    reader.decrypt("my-secret-password")

# Add all pages to the writer
for page in reader.pages:
    writer.add_page(page)

# Save the new PDF to a file
with open("decrypted-pdf.pdf", "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```